# All roots of the equation $a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+.....+a_{n-1}z+a_n=n$,lie outside the circle with center at the origin and radius $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Show that all roots of the equation $a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+.....+a_{n-1}z+a_n=n$,where $|a_i|\leq1,i=0,1,2,3...n$ lie outside the circle with center at the origin and radius $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

---

It seems that we need to prove $|z|\geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$
But i am stuck and i have no idea how to start with.Please help.

Comment: Use the Cauchy (lower) bound for the modulus of the roots of a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

If $|z|\le\dfrac{n-1}n$

$|\sum_{r=0}^na_rz^{n-r}|\le\sum_{r=0}^n|a_rz^{n-r}|\le\sum_{r=0}^n|z^{n-r}|$ as $|a_r|\le1$

Now, $\sum_{r=0}^n|z^{n-r}|=\sum_{u=0}^n|z^u|=\dfrac{1-|z|^{n+1}}{1-|z|}\leq n\left[1-\left(\dfrac{n-1}n\right)^{n+1}\right]<n$

Comment: How does it prove the given question,i did not understand.Did you use Cauchy theorem on bounds of moduli of roots of the polynomial?@lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: @Brahmagupta, I've used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: Sir,Is $\sum_{r=0}^{n}|z^{n-r}|<n$ a contradiction?Is $\sum_{r=0}^{n}|z^{n-r}|\geq n$?

Comment: @Brahmagupta, If $|z|\le\dfrac{n-1}n,$  $$|\sum_{r=0}^na_rz^{n-r}|<n$$  But we need  $$\sum_{r=0}^na_rz^{n-r}=n$$